# Auto update a week of dates each new week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to track weekly transactions, I already have a way to reset the user inputs at the end of the week, but I need a way to auto update the dates, it could be done manually but it's a bunch of dates to remember to all change at once and could make a lot of issues if they're not updated.

I couldn't really find any basic formulas or commands doing exact what I wanted or close to it. I plan to just set it on a timer to run at the end of the day Friday every week if it's a script.

Example image

[image: 1]

Comment: Date().getDay() return integers 0 - 7 Zero is Sunday and 7 is Saturday. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: @Cooper how exactly would that be applied to be a static date for a full week then change automatically after 1 week?

Comment: The getDay() function returns the same integer for each day of the week.  Essential it tells you which column to put it in from some starting offset.

Answer (score 0):

If you will never need to freeze the dates (by, say, not running the script), consider just using a formula to always 'live' display the nearest dates. First, make sure your date cells are actually set with Format→Number→Date to be real dates and not merely a text string of numbers and slashes. Worth noting here that accordingly, these cells will need to go through a Paste Special as Values Only from now on, being formulas.

Building up formulas to something suitable, we could change your first date to:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())
```

That will always give you ((the current date) minus (the current day of the week, in days)) …which will always equal the date of the most recent Saturday.

We can use that same formula for each day, but then offset them. Your picture's dates start not on a Saturday as above but on a Friday, so we can subtract 1 for the first day, add 0 to the next, add 1 to the next and so on until the last day:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+3
```

Now there's the issue of when the week rolls over to the next set of dates. You said an updater script may run EoD Friday and reiterated in a comment that the dates must not update on a one-at-a-time basis, but rather roll over all at once.

Adding one more day to subtract from TODAY() will, rather than the most recent Saturday, give us the most recent Friday. And since we're "adding one more to be subtracted," we'll need to fix the offset by adding one more there as well; to keep the first day on Friday (so e.g. the Tuesday's trailing `+3` goes to `+4`). With midnight Friday as our new weekly reset, the first date cell could then have the formula:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+1)+0
```

to go 0 days past the most recent Friday. All the other dates would retain that `TODAY()+1` rollover, but would in turn each add one to the trailing offset for `+0`, `+1`, `+2`, `+3`, and `+4` respectively.

[image: screenshot reflecting above formulas and resulting calculated dates]

I've made some assumptions about your date ranges and weekly reset, but I hope with the above descriptions, small tweaks are sufficient to get it displaying and resetting the correct dates automatically.